# How to Go To Source Code Definition (not Metadata) from C# to F# in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have a small C# Console Application that has a F# Project Reference.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var number = FS.DecodeRomanNumeral("XV");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

On the F# project, I have this code:

```
module FS

open System

/// Decodes a Roman Number string to a int number // https://twitter.com/nikoloz_p/status/1421218836896960515
let DecodeRomanNumeral RomanNumeral =
    let DigitToNumber = function
        | 'I' -> 1
        | 'V' -> 5
        | 'X' -> 10
        | 'L' -> 50
        | 'C' -> 100
        | 'D' -> 500
        | 'M' -> 1000
        | c -> failwith (sprintf "Invalid digit %c" c)
        
    let rec sum' Numbers = 
        match Numbers with
        | [] -> 0
        | x::y::rest when x < y -> y - x + sum' rest
        | x::rest -> x + sum' rest
    
    RomanNumeral 
        |> Seq.map DigitToNumber
        |> Seq.toList
        |> sum'
```

When I click on the **DecodeRomanNumeral** word and press F12
it brings the Disassembler window, instead of the actual F# source code that is on the referenced project. I noted that this behavior occurs in Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.10.4) and also Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.0.0 Preview 2.1)

[image: Disassembler]

I double checked and I added a Project Reference on the C# Project, making a reference to the F#

[image: Add Project Reference]

I need that it goes from the C# to the actual F# code when I press **F12** (Go To Definition).

How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, VS doesn't support that yet. Only from F# to C# works since VS 16.10: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/f-and-f-tools-update-for-visual-studio-16-10/#better-mixing-of-c-and-f-projects-in-your-solution

Personally, I've resorted to JetBrains Rider just for this, where it works very well.